# ASP.NET Identity: Authorize attribute with roles doesn't work on Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-identity

I just published my new ASP.NET MVC web site with Identity and OWIN authorization on Azure. Front-end works great, but got a problem with back-end. I use [Authorize] attribute with my admin controllers to check if user has a required role to access it, like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

On localhost even when using remote Azure SQL database it works fine.
But on Azure, any controller with authorize attribute with roles loading several minutes and then throws:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Authorize attribute without roles works fine.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with your SQL Server. Is your database an on-premise one or do you use an Azure SQL DB? Make sure that your connection string is correct and that you can connect to your database.

Comment: As I sayed, I use Azure DB all the time. If I run website from my local computer using Azure DB, everything works fine. But if I publish site to Azure (without changing any line of code), problem appears.

Comment: Your Azure DB is configured to "Allow Windows Azure Services" to connect?

Comment: Yes, it is configured.

Comment: Hi. Have you found a solution to your problem? I am sitting on the exact same issue, and it would be highly appreciated if you posted your solution. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't really solve the Azure problem, ended up writing my own Authorization attribute. The problem seems to be in `User.IsInRole()` method, so just avoid it.

Answer (score 16):

Adding this code to the web.config fixes the issue.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="RoleManager" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

I know this is late now but I have a real answer for you. Thought I'd share it anyway as I just wasted a few hours on it myself.

Info found from [this post](http://blog.luppes.com/2013/12/08/mvc5-authentication-roles-failure/)

Comment: Thank you, this finally solved it for me after many hours of testing and searching.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem because I was using an old form of Identity: the     `<rolemanager>`. If you are using asp.net identity 2 then you want to have have `<rolemanager>` disabled (which it is by default - i.e. have no reference to it in your web.config).