# ASP.NET MVC 5 Azure Website fails to connect to SQL Azure DB on some views due to role based [Authorize] attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, web-config, connection-string, azure-sql-database

We have an ASP.NET MVC 5 website, which works fine when we run it locally with Visual Studio. When run locally the website is connected to two SQL Express databases (the AspNetUsers & our Content DB). We connect to the content database using Entity Framework.

We deployed the website to Azure and migrated the 2 databases to SQL-Azure databases.

Here are the connectionstring within the web.config

```xml
<connectionStrings>    
<add name="AspNetUsersDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:ZZZ.database.windows.net,
1433;Initial Catalog=ZZZ;User ID=ZZZ@ZZZ;Password=ZZZ;" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<add name="Group5DatabaseConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=YYY.database.windows.net,
1433;Initial Catalog=YYY;User ID=YYY@YYY;Password=YYY;" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<add name="Group5DatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Group5Model.csdl|
res://*/Models.Group5Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.Group5Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string=&quot;data source=XXX.database.windows.net,1433;
InitialCatalog=XXX;UserID=XXX@XXX;Password=XXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
App=EntityFramework&quot;"providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

It appears that these are linked up to the website correctly, as the connection string in the web.config matches with the connection string in Azure correctly as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724682/azure-website-cannot-access-azure-db) and as most views on the website work fine.

However when trying to open two of the views, the following error appears:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to 
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name 
>   is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated 
>   in the code.
>
> **SQLExpress database file auto-creation error:**
>
> The connection string specifies a local Sql Server Express instance using a database 
>   location within the application's App_Data directory.
>
> The provider attempted to automatically create the application services database because 
>   the provider determined that the database does not exist. The following configuration 
>   requirements are necessary to successfully check for existence of the application 
>   services database and automatically create the application services database:
>
> If the application is running on either Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008R2, special 
>   configuration steps are necessary to enable automatic creation of the provider database. 
>   Additional information is available at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=160102. 
>   If the application's App_Data directory does not already exist, the web server account must 
>   have read and write access to the application's directory. This is necessary because the web 
>   server account will automatically create the App_Data directory if it does not already exist.
>
> If the application's App_Data directory already exists, the web server account only 
>   requires read and write access to the application's App_Data directory. This is necessary 
>   because the web server account will attempt to verify that the Sql Server Express database 
>   already exists within the application's App_Data directory. Revoking read access on the 
>   App_Data directory from the web server account will prevent the provider from correctly 
>   determining if the Sql Server Express database already exists. This will cause an error when 
>   the provider attempts to create a duplicate of an already existing database. Write access is 
>   required because the web server account's credentials are used when creating the new database.
>
> Sql Server Express must be installed on the machine.
>   The process identity for the web 
>   server account must have a local user profile. See the readme document for details on 
>   how to create a local user profile for both machine and domain accounts.

It seems as the following line might be most significant in the error message:

> The connection string specifies a local Sql Server Express instance using a database location within the application's App_Data directory.

The two views that don't work are both instantiating the `AccountController` and use the following method within it:

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    // ...
    public string FindUserArea(string id)
    {
        int locationId = FindUserLocationId(id);                
        Location location = db.Locations.FirstOrDefault(p => p.LocationID == locationId);

        return (string) (location.Suburb.SuburbName + " > "
            + location.Suburb.Region.RegionName + " > "
            + location.Suburb.Region.Province.ProvinceName);
    }
    // ...
}
```

We first suspected there to be an error within the `AccountController`, but another view which also uses the method above displays fine. We then thought there could still be the possibility of an error related to `InitializeSimpleMembership` as this came up in a few questions (we weren't 100% sure about the meaning/effect of `SimpleMembership`). We followed the lead in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964004/authentication-problems-after-publishing-mvc-4-app-to-azure), but successfully adding `InitializeSimpleMembership` based on the suggestions [in this article](http://forums.asp.net/t/1840044.aspx?How%20to%20enable%20SimpleMembership%20in%20MVC%204) did not resolve the error.

Also, the same error appears at registration for one of two users, however the `AspNetUser` Azure DB still updates and once refreshing the site login with the new user is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After systematically pinpointing the error down to its root we found that the problem originated in the role based `[Authorize]` attribute, exactly the same problem as in [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941027/asp-net-identity-authorize-attribute-with-roles-doesnt-work-on-azure).

Apparently there is some problem in the `User.IsInRole()` behind the scenes when connected to SQL-Azure. While this usually could have been solved with enabling Simple Membership -— in our case we were not able to do so easily because Simple Membership requires the `AspNetUser` Id to be an int and not a string (which seemed rather tricky to implement with the [Identity Model](http://typecastexception.com/post/2013/11/11/Extending-Identity-Accounts-and-Implementing-Role-Based-Authentication-in-ASPNET-MVC-5.aspx) we used because the Id inherently needs to be a string).

Initially we didn't pick up on the issue with the SimpleMembership as the line below did not fire early enough in the App_Start and we only realised there is an issue once we put it into global.

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseFile("MySecurity.sdf", "Users", "UserID", "Username", true);
```

So we also ended up writing our own authorization method as below:

```
if (User.Identity.GetUserId() == null)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
}
else
{
    var c = new AccountController();
    string UserRole = c.FindUserRoleById(User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString());

    if (UserRole != "DesiredUserRole")
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }
    else
    {
        // Desired User stuff
    }
}
```

which calls `FindUserRoleById`:

```
public string FindUserRoleById(string id)
{
    var user = UserManager.FindById(id);
    var userroles = user.Roles;
    string userrole = "";

    foreach (var x in userroles)
    {
        if (userrole != "Admin")
        {
            if (x.Role.Name.ToString() == "Admin")
            {
                userrole = "Admin";
            }
            else if (x.Role.Name.ToString() == "User2")
            {
                userrole = "User2";
            }
            else if (x.Role.Name.ToString() == "User3")
            {
                userrole = "User3";
            }
        }
    }
    return userrole;
}
```

Obviously this is not as slick as the simple role check of the `[Authorize]` attribute, but it did the trick in this case and works just fine.

I'd still be interested if anyone has a better solution.

Comment: With the same problem, after hours of testing and searching as well, the top voted answer here fixed it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941027/asp-net-identity-authorize-attribute-with-roles-doesnt-work-on-azure.  It also links to this blog post describing the problem (in my case at least): http://blog.luppes.com/2013/12/08/mvc5-authentication-roles-failure/

Answer (score 2):

This does seem quite odd, I have seen other odd behaviour when SQL connections are made from a mix of Entity Framework context and standard connection, however if you just have 1 single database connection string that may not be the issue.

Something else I have come across, but mostly due to deadlock and timeout issues is EF DbExecutionStrategy which can re-try calls based on various errors including transient connection issue, this may be something to try, see these links:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/758469/Implementing-Connection-Resiliency-with-Entity-Fra

http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/ef6-connection-resiliency-for-sql-azure-when-does-it-actually-do-its-thing/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I implemented the connection resiliency, unfortunately the error remained.
We actually have 2 database connection strings that link up to Azure, the AspNetUser DB and a general content DB. The edmx model just links to the general DB. Do you think there might be a chance that the error gets resolved if we were to merge the databases?

Comment: I updated the question to include the connectionstring in the web.config

Comment: If there is no real need to have 2 databases, it may be worth joining them. ie create user tables and use a custom membership provider (or custom asp.net identity classes) Also but it may be that both databases are being called (using separate connections) in a single transaction, mixing thing ups like that may reset one of the connections?

Comment: Thank you for the helpful suggestions, they are much appreciated! We ended up identifying the problem within the role based [Authorize] and I added our solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was an issue related to authorize and isinrole() method. to solve it a had to add the following lines to the web.config :

```
  <system.webServer>
...
 <modules>
...
        <remove name="RoleManager" />
..
    </modules>
```